# Creating a new rotopaint brush stroke based on a set of given x&y positions (Python, Nuke)

Tags: python, line, nuke

I have a set of x&y positions in a list that I want to create a new rotopaint brush stroke from.

Here is the set of positions =
[[544, 624], [556, 804], [578, 862], [632, 922], [706, 958], [826, 964], [890, 938], [902, 910], [908, 862], [902, 736], [908, 592], [928, 538], [982, 518], [1042, 528], [1288, 676], [1364, 736], [1412, 800], [1444, 898], [1454, 904], [1474, 850], [1480, 772], [1474, 722], [1428, 540], [1428, 488], [1438, 478], [1464, 468], [1500, 476], [1728, 656], [1788, 720], [1846, 844], [1864, 684], [1900, 562], [1916, 468]]

I was wondering if there was any way to create a new stroke with a control point at each of these positions using python in nuke?

If anyone could provide any links or ideas they may have, that would be a great help. Thanks so much.